# print in middle of page with font auto adjusted to max in html

Tags: php, html, fonts

I have to print output onto sticker or size 1.181in 1.181in. I have tried numerous things , however font has no effect, even though if font becomes slight bigger it cuts the content. I have used vw, %, px but no significant difference. What I want is to fit the page with max font size.
Here's my code:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<?php
    //require 'conn.php';
    require 'db_config.php';
    $pid=$_GET['id'];
    $prnt=$_GET['p'];
?>
  <html lang="en">

  <head>
    <style>
      .table {
        width: 100%;
        margin-bottom: 20px;
      }
      
      .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>td,
      .table-striped tbody>tr:nth-child(odd)>th {
        background-color: #f9f9f9;
      }
      
      @page {
        size: 1.181in 1.181in;
        /* auto is the initial value */
        /*margin: 6cm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
        /* margin-left: 1cm;
         /*margin-right: 6cm;*/
        /*margin-top: 1cm*/
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <style>
    @page {
      size: 1.181in 1.181in;
      /* auto is the initial value */
      /*margin: 6cm;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
      margin-left: 1cm;
      /*tried removing left and right b
         /*margin-right: 6cm;*/
      margin-top: 1cm
    }
  </style>

  <body>
    <?php
                require 'conn.php';
                
                //$query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `product` where product_id='$pid'");
                $query = $conn->query("SELECT * FROM `prodlist` where slno='$pid'");
                
                while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()){
                    $pname=$fetch['prodname'];
                    $pnamel2=$fetch['prodnamel2'];
                }
                while($prnt>0)
                {
            ?>


      <h2 style="break-after: always;">
        <font size="100%">
          <?php echo $pname?><br><?php echo $pnamel2?>
        </font>
      </h2>

      <?
                    $prnt--;
                }?>
  </body>
```

Here's the screenshot:

[image]

**EDIT:**
I made changes in @page css

```
<style>
    @page {
        size: auto;   /* auto is the initial value */
        margin: 0;  /* this affects the margin in the printer settings */
    }
</style>
```

and it gave me this
As I said I have 2 lines to prints, so 2nd line word prints in next sticker
[image]

Comment: Where is `$prnt` declared? Please provide a complete [mre].

Comment: i have added the complete code, please review

Comment: `$pname` is declared inside the while loop, its scope is within that loop. But you are accessing it outside the loop.

Comment: But the loop works

Comment: Is your PHP working? It appears so. My recommendation is to view the rendered HTML and CSS and paste that here, and remove the PHP tag from the question. You might get more eyeballs on it then.

Comment: @mark, of course the loop will work, this like `<?php echo $pname?>` shouldn't work.

Comment: @ChrisHaas, I would not recommend removing PHP tag, since the issue is likely related to PHP.

Comment: @kiner_shah what you recommend , where the fault is i am pretty something very simple I am missing out

Comment: Try `$pname = ''; $pnamel2 = ''; while($fetch = $query->fetch_array()){ $pname=$fetch['prodname']; $pnamel2=$fetch['prodnamel2']; }`